# Compounding Equivalence

Tags: interest-rates, continuous-time, compounding

I am trying to understand under what circumstances or transformations would
$[1+(E_2-E_1)*\frac{d}{360}]$ equal to $(\frac{1+E_2}{1+E_1})^{\frac{d}{360}}$.

For context, $E_2, E_1$ are interest rates.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: They are only approximately equal if $E_1,E_2,\frac{d}{360}$ are small enough. The first expression is a linearization of the other.

Answer (score 1):

They're not equivalent, but you can use log identities to derive something similar after applying a log.

Eg,

$ln\left(\left(\frac{1+E_2}{1+E_1}\right)^{\frac{d}{360}}\right)$

$\frac{d}{360}*\left(1+E_2-\left(1+E_1\right)\right)   $

$\left(E_2-E_1\right)*\frac{d}{360}$